# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error in Swift - terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Tags: xcode, swift, nsexception

I have looked for answers to this error but haven't found the answer.

When I try to run my app it crashes and this screen pops up https://www.dropbox.com/s/po8h36keeo5dt59/Screenshot%202014-08-20%2016.40.55.png

Here is my debug section:

```
2014-08-20 16:48:17.346 Shots.Implementing[37057:4467914] Could not load the "image" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.vumble.Shots-Implementing"
2014-08-20 16:48:18.216 Shots.Implementing[37057:4467914] Could not load the "avatar" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.vumble.Shots-Implementing"
2014-08-20 16:48:18.220 Shots.Implementing[37057:4467914] Failed to set (keyPath) user defined inspected property on (UIImageView): [<UIImageView 0x7fb2c2fe0b10> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key keyPath.
2014-08-20 16:48:18.223 Shots.Implementing[37057:4467914] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Shots_Implementing.Home 0x7fb2c2c27dc0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key commentsView.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104fd33e5 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000106ae6967 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104fd3029 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x00000001053ea383 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 259
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104f1d3f0 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000105b1d16d -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1506
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010597fd78 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 242
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000105980368 -[UIViewController loadView] + 109
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001059805d9 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 75
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000105980a6e -[UIViewController view] + 27
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001058a12b1 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 58
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001058a164a -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 276
    12  UIKit                               0x00000001058ada81 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    13  UIKit                               0x00000001058585cd -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2628
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010585b29c -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1350
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010585a168 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
    16  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010830b513 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 16
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104f08aac __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104efe7f5 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104efe5b5 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104efd9f6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000105859bdf -[UIApplication _run] + 413
    22  UIKit                               0x000000010585c990 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    23  Shots.Implementing                  0x0000000104afaa5e top_level_code + 78
    24  Shots.Implementing                  0x0000000104afaa9a main + 42
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010706e145 start + 1
    26  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: does your `Home` class have a property `commentsView`?